# Jquery form submit doesn't work even after renaming input field to something other than "submit"

Tags: jquery

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="save-chart-form">
// Some fields, none named "submit"
<input id="saveChartButton" name="commit" class="default-button-jsd disablebutton" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#save-chart-form" ).submit( function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $( "#saveChartButton" ).val( "Please be patient, it might take a while to prepare your chart" );
        $( "#save-chart-form" ).submit() // THIS won't work
    } );
} );
```

$( "#save-chart-form" ).submit() is supposed to submit the form but it does nothing. You can notice that I already renamed the form submit button to something other than 'submit' which is the traditional fix for this issue.
Using jquery 3.1.1.

What is the culprit ?

EDIT: changing the jquery call to

```
$("#save-chart-form").click(function (event) {....
```

won't fix the problem

Comment: I might be wrong but you probably looping the submit here. The `$( "#save-chart-form" ).submit()` will trigger the `submit` event handler again, which gets prevented inside the event handler

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking what you really want is `$("#save-chart-form").click(function (event) { ...`?

Comment: @MattCremeens this won't fix the problem.

Comment: And don't you need something in your `action= ...` for this to work?

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to fix things

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Are you sure you have a valid action on your form? Check your developer console for errors (press F12 and go to console tab then post here results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your console (firefox, press f12) you might get an error: too much recursion. If you put a callback at a form, it would be to prevent submitting when something is not right. So the callback should return a boolean:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#save-chart-form" ).submit( function( event ) {
        $( "#saveChartButton" ).val( "Please be patient, it might take a while to prepare your chart" );

    if(valid){
        return true; // this will submit
    } else {
        return false; // this will prevent the submit
    }
    } );
} );
```

So remove event.preventDefault(). that will disable any submit posibility and replace that with a return

Answer (score 0):

I will change the type of the input from `submit` to `button` and add an onclick event attribute which will fill the button's value and submit the form.

Considering your code, the label will only shown for like for 0.001s, the submission will take place immediately, if I'm right.